# You are trying to close View Model associated with Fragment when currently top Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

My app is on Xamarin.Android with MvvMCross v 5+.

I'm trying to implement the follow sample https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/develop/TestProjects/Android-Support/Fragments/Example.Droid

Here's My Home View Where i will have all my "DrawerLayout,Toolbar,AppbarLayout,FrameLayout,NavigationView"

```html
[Activity(Label = "View for HomeViewModel",
          LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop
          )]
    public class HomeView : MvxAppCompatActivity<HomeViewModel>, INavigationActivity
    {
    }
```

But in My Homeview I'm Creating Whole DrawerLayout in Same Layout.so whenvever i click navigation menu items i switiching fragments like this

```html
switch (e.MenuItem.ItemId)
                {
                    case Resource.Id.nav_home:
                        ViewModel.ShowViewModelAndroid(typeof(OrdersViewModel));
                        //ListItemClicked(0);
                        break;
                    case Resource.Id.nav_friends:
                        ListItemClicked(1);
                        break;
                    case Resource.Id.nav_profile:
                        ListItemClicked(2);
                        break;
                }
```

MY Fragment

```html
[MvxFragment(typeof(HomeViewModel), Resource.Id.content_frame, true)]
    [Register("Peeto.Droid.Views.Fragments.OrdersFragment")]
    public class OrdersFragment: BaseStateFragment<OrdersViewModel>
    {
    }
```

Whenever I click on nav_home it is throwing following error

> Unhandled Exception:
>
> System.InvalidOperationException: You are trying to close ViewModel associated with Fragment when currently top Activity (Peeto.Droid.Views.HomeView does not implement IMvxFragmentHost interface!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are using 5.0 code while your packages are on 5.2. This sample is only valid on 5.2. You've got to change your attribute to `[MvxFragmentPresentation]` and update to the new presenter.

Comment: Thank you so much Martin :), One more doubt why MvvmCross.Droid.Shared is not installing with 5.2.0 MvvMcross ?

Comment: Because it is removed. Its explained in the blog post.